# Find a function so that in $(0,0)$ is an isolated local maximum, in $(-17,0)$ and $(0,3)$ are an isolated minimum.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, examples-counterexamples

My task is to find a continous differentiable function by knowing located isolated extreme in point $(0,0)$ is an isolated local maximum, in point $(-17,0)$ and $(0,3)$ are an isolated minimum.

Do you know a function? I can do the proof but I can't find a *function* can you please help me?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the function needs to be a function of two variables? Like $f(x,y)$ ... ?

Comment: yes right 2 variables

Comment: Well, if the only condition is that those should be isolated extrema, then you could just set
$$
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
1, & (x,y)=(0,0) \\
-1, & (x,y) = (-17,0) \\
-1, & (x,y) = (0,3) \\
0, &  \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and call it a day.

Comment: I'll hazard a guess that OP would like the function to be continuous, maybe even smooth, possibly a polynomial.

Comment: it has to be continous and differentiable sorry. i think it has to be a function in one row and not like that

Comment: Are you allowed to have other extreme points, or do these need to be the only ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. Consider the "eggbox"-shaped surface (see [here](https://mathcurve.com/surfaces.gb/boiteaoeufs/boiteaoeufs.shtml)) with equation :

$$z=\cos(\pi x)\cos(\pi y)\tag{1}$$

[image]

This surface has a local maximum in $(0,0)$ and, nearby, local minima in $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ (of course, due to periodicity, there will be an infinite number of those...)

Now, make a change of variable using the linear transformation mapping $(1,0),(0,1)$ onto $(-17,0),(0,3)$ resp., yielding the following equation of the "stretched" surface :

$$z=\cos(\pi x/17)\cos(\pi y/3)\tag{2}$$

One can easily check the properties of local extrema because expression (2) takes its values in $[-1,1]$, with value $-1$ (resp. $+1$) being taken necessarily at a local minima (resp. local maxima).

Comment: haha i already got this advice from our professor i thought maybe  (pi/3) but i dont know how to change that i get -17 and 3

Comment: Is it clear now with the explicit expression I gave ?

Comment: yess thank you very much i will try the proof with the usual way in my math course :) and then i will come back here

Comment: ok yes it worked thank you very very very much Jean Marie :)

Comment: @math3290495 the way to thank someone on this website is to "accept" the person's answer by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Comment: thank you gerry . did i thank you right or is there another rule?